# Client Application Services - Authentication from WPF client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Client Application Services for Client (WPF) authentication with ASP.Net membership, which is working just fine. However, on the server I have additional MVC queries that I must authenticate when calling them from the client. When looking at the available  Membership.ValidateUser call, I fail to see how this helps me in any way, as I need to validate every single call.

I assume sticking `[Authorize]` on each MVC call is the first step.

Can I get a security token, or extract a cookie for the CookieContainer, or am I simply misunderstanding something here?

Comment: When you say [Authenticate] you mean [Authorize] right. " I have additional MVC queries that I must authenticate when calling them from the client". Who is the client? The WPF application itself?

Comment: Thanks, correction applied. And yes, it's the WPF application which is the client.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you ASP.Net MVC site, WCF services are hosted in same virtual application and ASP.Net compatibility mode is on. 
If you are using WPF to authenticate your user by calling a web service do the following

On Server side

- Implement code to do authentication
- Once authentication is successful
  create a form authentication cookie
  and add it to response cookie
  collection.

On the client side

- The client class that you are using
  to connect to authentication service
  should contain a static CookieContainer class instance.
- Once authentication is
  successful add the cookie received to
  this cookie container and pass it along every subsequent request.

Hence forth all request to ASP.Net MVC application or any service would contain the cookie and the user would get authorize automatically. Check [this blog post](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/various-clients-and-forms-authentication/) for sample 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this in anyway integrate with Client Application Services. I mean why have a separate login method returning a cookie, when we already got the ValidateUser method of Client Application Services?

Comment: The blog post is just an example. When you call ValidateUser on the CAS it would add an authentication cookie to http header and that would get passed on all subsequent requests